# How to take json response in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, arrays

I am making a ajax request in jquery and in return getting the response but not as an array.

```
{"ErrorCode":0,"SeriesSocialStats":{"8970471":{"faves":1,"friendFaves":0,"friendLikes":0,"likes":1,"myFaves":1,"myLikes":0,"seriesId":"8970471"}}}
{"ErrorCode":0,"SeriesSocialStats":{"184072":{"faves":2,"friendFaves":0,"friendLikes":0,"likes":2,"myFaves":1,"myLikes":0,"seriesId":"184072"}}}
```

I want to merge the above two response and create an array something like this :

```
{"faves":1,"friendFaves":0,"friendLikes":0,"likes":1,"myFaves":1,"myLikes":0,"seriesId":"8970471"},{"faves":2,"friendFaves":0,"friendLikes":0,"likes":2,"myFaves":1,"myLikes":0,"seriesId":"184072"}
```

Please suggest how to do it. I want to take it in array and store it locally may be in config varaible `get:[]` and then access somewhat like `config.get[data["seriesId"]]`.

Comment: you can start by changing how the server replies with the JSON. turn that reply into an array first. you can't parse JSON like that.

Comment: but how to do that because i need to skip `"8970471":` from each response. Also i am not able to access the response after that part because this is the seriesId and i cant give it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you need to convert your response into an array** of objects:

```
var response = [
    {"ErrorCode":0,...},
    {"ErrorCode":0,...},
    {"ErrorCode":0,...},
]
```

in actual:

```
jsonResponse = [
    {"ErrorCode":0,"SeriesSocialStats":{"8970471":{"faves":1,"friendFaves":0,"friendLikes":0,"likes":1,"myFaves":1,"myLikes":0,"seriesId":"8970471"}}},
    {"ErrorCode":0,"SeriesSocialStats":{"184072":{"faves":2,"friendFaves":0,"friendLikes":0,"likes":2,"myFaves":1,"myLikes":0,"seriesId":"184072"}}}
]
```

then loop through:

```
var newArray = []
for(var i=0;i<jsonResponse.length;i++){             //loop through items
    var stats = jsonResponse[i].SeriesSocialStats;
    for(key in stats){                              //loop through "SeriesSocialStats" numbers
        newArray.push(stats[key]);
    }
}
```

so it will be like:

```
newArray = [
    {"faves":1,"friendFaves":0,"friendLikes":0,"likes":1,"myFaves":1,"myLikes":0,"seriesId":"8970471"},
    {"faves":2,"friendFaves":0,"friendLikes":0,"likes":2,"myFaves":1,"myLikes":0,"seriesId":"184072"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
var obj1 = {"ErrorCode":0,"SeriesSocialStats":{"8970471":{"faves":1,"friendFaves":0,"friendLikes":0,"likes":1,"myFaves":1,"myLikes":0,"seriesId":"8970471"}}};

var obj2 = {"ErrorCode":0,"SeriesSocialStats":{"184072":{"faves":2,"friendFaves":0,"friendLikes":0,"likes":2,"myFaves":1,"myLikes":0,"seriesId":"184072"}}};

var arr = [];

arr.push(ob1.SeriesSocialStats);
arr.push(ob2.SeriesSocialStats);
```

Comment: i cant create seperate variable for each response because the response are many and i need i single way to push it in an array

Answer (score 0):

Best way convert your server response to array structure, like mentioned by Joseph, instead of doing double processing from object to array.